# Subquery v/s inner join in sql server

Tags: optimization, sql, sql-server

I have  following queries

First one using inner join

> ```
> SELECT item_ID,item_Code,item_Name 
> FROM [Pharmacy].[tblitemHdr] I INNER JOIN  EMR.tblFavourites F ON I.item_ID=F.itemID
> WHERE F.doctorID = @doctorId AND F.favType = 'I'
> ```

second one using sub query like

```
SELECT item_ID,item_Code,item_Name from [Pharmacy].[tblitemHdr]
WHERE item_ID IN
(SELECT itemID FROM EMR.tblFavourites
WHERE doctorID = @doctorId AND favType = 'I'
)
```

In this item table `[Pharmacy].[tblitemHdr]` Contains 15 columns and 2000 records. And `[Pharmacy].[tblitemHdr]` contains 5 columns and around 100 records. in this scenario `which query gives me better performance?`

Comment: Have you checked the [execution plans](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Examining_Query_Execution_Plans) for the two queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server query analyzer is smart enough to understand that these queries are identical (given that `item_ID` is unique in `EMR.tblFavourites` for a certain doctorID/favType pair).

They should yield exactly the same execution plan, and thus they are equal in terms of performance. I would prefer second variant though...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Microsoft SQL server (I assume that this is actual SQL server mentioned here). Actually I'm pretty sure that `IN` will not produce multiplication of rows if there is two entries for single `F.itemID` in contrast with `INNER JOIN`.

I suspect that with absence of unique index on `F.itemID` performance may differ too. Probably `IN` will prefer to ordered unique set of relations while `FROM` will consider statistics of both tables more equally than `IN`.

P.S. I prefer `JOIN` because of giving hint for optimizer while dropping off additional constraint. And it looks a bit more readable as for me (less amount of `SELECT`).